# Distinction between nonclustered index and covering index

Tags: sql-server, indexing

May be a weird title, but I will try to express my dilemma.

What is real distinction between non-clustered index with, let's say, three columns (ie. `FirstName`, `LastName` and `BirthDate`) and covering index where we have two index columns (`FirstName` and `LastName`) and one included column `BirthDate`?

Is there any performance boosting using one type over other? What is happened in both index type when we update values in `BirthDate` column?

What we gain/lose with using clean non-clustered over covering index, while in both indexes we have all three value right there in index, without need to make extra task to get out data from page file.

Is there any distinction in index structure?

Maybe is question too broad, but problem is simple.

Comment: You can spare some time and look through this series of articles about indexes - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/

Comment: @gotqn: excellent series of articles, indeed !

Comment: I agree, after I look at this article, i've seen that there is a detailed explanation about indexes. +1 from me :)

Answer (score 5):

The distinction is this: *included* columns cannot be used to limit the rows returned - e.g. they cannot be used in a `WHERE` clause (since they're not part of the index navigation tree - they're only included - as their name implies - on the *leaf level* of the index).

On the other hand: since they are not part of the navigation structure, they also don't bloat up your index - and they can be larger than the max. of 900 bytes that an index entry is limited to. So if you have large columns (e.g. `VARCHAR(MAX)` or large binary columns), those can *never* be indexed - but they can be *included* on the leaf level of the index

**PS:** as @gotqn pointed out in this comment on the question - here's a really good, extensive, well-written series of articles on everything concerning indexes in SQL Server:

[SQL Server Central: Stairway to SQL Server Indexes](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/)

Highly recommended!